# Facebook account download automation with python?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

As a regular task within my job role i often have to download full Facebook accounts from within a users account. I am trying to improve my workflow and automate this if i can.

I have tried searching for this topic on the site and although many cover the login part i am yet to locate a question that deals with the popup windows of Facebook. If i am wrong i apologise and please amend the post accordingly.

As a starting point i have decided to start learning python and am using this to script the process with a little help from selenium and Chrome Driver. I have managed to write the code to login and navigate to the correct page and click the initial link 'download a copy'. I am struggling however to get the script to locate and click the 'Start My Archive' button within the popup window.

Here is the code that i have used so far including the several alternative code blocks that i have tried commented out at the bottom:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Global Variables
target = "john.doe.7"
username = "john@doe.com"
password = "Password"
sleep = 5

#Finds and locates the ChromeDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Python35-32\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe")

#Set Chrome Options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

#Directs browser to webpage
driver.get('http://www.facebook.com');

#code block to log in user
def logmein():
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
    search_box.send_keys(username)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('pass')
    search_box.send_keys(password)
    search_box.submit()

#code to go to specific URL
def GoToURL(URL):
    time.sleep(sleep) # Let the user actually see something!
    driver.get(URL);    

logmein()

GoToURL('https://www.facebook.com/'+'settings')

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Download a copy')
link.click()

#driver.find_element_by.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Start My Archive')]").click()

#driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button._42ft._42fu.selected._42gz._42gy').click()

#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Start My Archive')]").click()

#driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button._42ft._42fu.layerConfirm.uiOverlayButton.selected._42g-._42gy').click()

#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains import driver

#buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//title[contains(text(),'Start My Archive')]")
#actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
#time.sleep(2)
#actions.click(button)
#actions.perform()
```

Comment: If Start My Archive is not a webelement and it is what windows is popping up, you cannot handle it with driver. There is class called Robot which can be used to handle windows based alerts. Do refer this
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/handle-alerts-popups-selenium-webdriver-selenium-tutorial-16/

Comment: @KishanPatel thank you for your link and tutorial. I will work through this and see if it helps. You mentioned about webelement's and i think the button is one. I have included the html from the page below which may help clarify whether it is or isnt this type of element. It also looks like there is a requirement to use javascript to get this to work but not sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your code and run if it is working or not. Always use CssSelector.

Look i ran the below code in eclipse with java and I'm not aware of python so if something is wrong in syntax , i apologies. Just Try this and see.

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
Startmyarchive = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.selected._42gz._42gy")
Startmyarchive.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
Acknowledge = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.layerConfirm.uiOverlayButton.selected._42g-._42gy")
Acknowledge.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
ClickOkay = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._42ft._42fu.layerCancel.uiOverlayButton.selected._42g-._42gy")
ClickOkay.click()
```

Happy Learning :-) Do reply back for any query.

Comment: Thank you for putting forward this code. I have tried it and it works so that it really helpful. I realised i didn't include the code as i said so thank you for taking the time to look further into this.

Comment: Yeah James. Enjoy. Come up with more queries. It is nice to learn always. :-)

Comment: Hello Kishan, I took on board your comment about always using CssSelector and am trying to progress my script to the next stage. With the help of your hint i can now get through to the "Input password" pop up but i am yet to establish if this is the same style popup as before because so far its not working! :-)

Comment: Hi James. So tell me exactly where are you stuck ? You logged in to the account. ? Or stuck there only?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply Kishnan. I can get all the way through to the pop up box that asks you to confirm you password which then allows the download of the archive. The issue i cant work out this time is how to get the focus on the password entry box so the password can be entered using something like the 'submit' function? It is possibly easier if i send you the code and or screen shot but unsure of the best way to do so? Thanks in advance, James